# searching emails in s3

Tags: email, search

I want to search for old emails/senders/subjects etc. in my samsung galaxy s3 email app. There doesn't seem to be a search function. Any ideas how to do this, or alternative mail apps which you can recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung Galaxy s3 I can hold down the menu button inside the built in mail app - This enables the search function.

You can search for

- All
- Title
- Sender
- Date
- Attachment
- Advanced (which is a combination of Title+Sender+Date)

Answer (score 0):

[Emoze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emoze.Emozesync) has a search function which is much better than any other email app I've tried.

Comment: Might be best to include a bit more information rather than just a linky and one-liner to save us linky-jumping :)